# Windows Forms, Delete prewritten Text in textbox when starting to type (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

You all know those Login Textboxes, where inside it says "Username" and "Password".
So my problem is, that i can´t find anything in the Internet that explains to me how i can detect if anything is written in the textbox.
Then i could use "Username" as a background image, that turns white when i start typing. Something like:

```
if (Textbox_is_not_empty)
{
   Change_Background_image_To_white_colour
}
```

Comment: Handle the `TextChanged` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can erase the text inside the `TextBox` by handling the `Enter` event.

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Clear();
}
```

And set the text to "Username" when you leave and the `TextBox` is empty.

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(textBox1.Text == "")
        textBox1.Text = "Username";
}
```

Comment: That didn´t work for me. I entered the methods into the Form.cs, but nothing happened when i compiled and tried

Comment: @JavaGamer You need to set the events on the TextBox. Click on [events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVtjr.png) on the `TextBox` and set the events on `Enter` and `Leave`